# How to set NTP tinker step (which unit)? and how to query?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

One of the workaround for old CentOS/CentOS kernel (6.1-6.3) which may "Systems hang due to leap-second livelock." ([quoting redhat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/154713)), is to set  `tinker step` in `/etc/ntp.conf`. Bug the documentation is not clear about the unit/syntax (http://doc.ntp.org/4.2.6p5/miscopt.html#tinker).

What is the exact syntax (unit) for `tinker step`?

Also, how can I query the current value of `tinker step` on a running NTP daemon?

Answer (score 0):

The unit seems to be seconds, so the line to add in `/etc/ntp.conf` should be:

```
tinker step 0.128
```

(This Should be 0.128s, which is the default value)